# How to rethrow an exception and return a value in c#?

Tags: c#, exception

Given the following code, how can I return some value (DateTime.Now.ToString()) if the exception is thrown?

```
public string DateToString(int year, int month, int day)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        return datetime.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //log error and rethrow
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you throw an exception, your method ends immediately.
There is no way to return a value too.

When you call a method which throws an exception, control will immediately transfer to a `catch` block.
You won't get any chance to observe or use the (nonexistent-) return value.

You should rethink your design.

Comment: no need to observe/use return value (in try code path) as stated in question

Comment: If there is no need to use the return value why return it? Just re-throw the exception. If you *really* need it, you could create your own wrapper exception that has two arguments, the real exception and the desired return value, but that is horrid.

Comment: @Michael - reread my comment. I meant there is no need to use the return `from the try portion` if and when it fails. I interpreted the question as "if parameters are invalid to form a date" -> return datetime.now instead" I thought the re-throwing the error part is just extraneous stemming from misunderstanding of how that works

Answer (score 4):

I think your question is wrongly worded.  It looks like you simply want a default value returned on exception.  Therefore

```
public string DateToString(int year, int month, int day)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        return datetime.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exObj)
    {
        //log error
        LogMyError(exObj);
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you do it in this way:

```
    bool IsValidDateTime(int year, int month, int day, out DateTime result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            result = DateTime.Now; // assign a value
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If you want a string just make sure return value is true and call

```
 result.ToString();
```

Comment: No.  You should return a `DateTime?`.

Comment: DateTime is not a nullable type. How do you know it's an 'invalid' value then? You could of course just let the exception ocurr and have the caller deal with it. But if you are validating user input I think it is better to validate with the TryParse pattern.

Comment: Adding `?` turns `DateTime` into a nullable type. That's what the `?` means. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx): "The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, where `T` is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable."

Comment: Oh my... How did I miss that. Thx for bringing it up!!

Answer (score 1):

Think about what throwing an exception actually entails. If your function *returns* a value, presumably you want to *use* that somewhere, right?

Like:

```
// Will a value be assigned to dateString, or will an exception be thrown?
string dateString = DateToString(2011, 2, 29);
```

If you want `DateToString` to *return* a value in the exceptional case above, then you want that value assigned to `dateString`, right? But then what do you want to do with the exception? Either you're going to continue or not; you can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: cyberkiwi grasped the question better than I did, but I'll let it stand as bad example of reading ;)

---

You can always define an own exception class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class OwnException : System.Exception
{
    public readonly MaybeDateTime;

    ...
    public OwnException (string message, System.Exception inner) :  base(message, inner) { maybe = null; }
    public OwnException (string message, System.Exception inner, DateTime maybe) :  base(message, inner) { MaybeDateTime = maybe; }
}
```

and throw this one (assigning *datetime*).

You would have to have to transfer the *DateTime datetime*-declaration outside of the try-catch-block and in your example SLaks is right: it would not make sense. *datetime* could only hold something meaningful if the return-Statement throws the caught exception. In other cases there might be useful applications.

Edit: Same could be done with a string, but to rethrow this as an exception if returning the current time resolves the situation in a good way would be somewhat idiotic. Did not read properly, as noted above.

Comment: I think @IanM want to return the current datetime [DateTime.Now.ToString()] rather than the value of the datetime instance [in the try block].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    public string DateToString(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        try
        {
            return datetime.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.HelpLink = datetime.ToString();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

//at caller side you can use ex.HelpLink to get the value